next.js metadata title template chaining
I’m working on a Next.js project with a nested file structure, and I want each layout level to add a title prefix recursively, so the final title is a combination of all layout titles up to the current page.
Here’s my folder structure:
├── app
│   ├── layout.tsx     // Title "Studio"      
│   ├── project-review
│   │   ├── layout.tsx     // Title "Studio - Project Review"  
│   │   ├── history
│   │   │   └── page.tsx       // // Title "Studio - Project Review - history"
│   │   └── page.tsx
│   └── page.tsx

In my root layout.tsx, I set the base title template:
// app/layout.tsx
export const metadata = {
  title: { template: 'Studio - %s', default: 'Studio' },
};

In next files :
// app/project-review/layout.tsx
export const metadata = {
  title: { template: 'Project Review - %s', default: 'Project reviews' },
};

// app/project-review/history/page.tsx
export const metadata = {
  title: { default: 'History' },
};

I would need the values from the title teplmate to be chained through all nested layouts
With this setup, the title displayed is Project Review - History instead of Studio - Project Review - History. It seems each metadata object in layouts replaces rather than appends to the previous metadata, so only the nearest title template is used.
Why This Approach Didn’t Meet My Needs
My goal is to have Next.js automatically combine titles across nested layouts without manually concatenating them in each layout. This would allow a scalable approach to managing complex page titles that dynamically reflect the structure of my app, where each layout contributes its own unique prefix.
Is there a way to achieve recursive title templating with metadata in Next.js, or would I need a custom solution to manually handle this inheritance?

metadata only affects the pages directly under it, which explains why the nearest title template overrides the previous ones.
But you can use Context to keep track of titles see below example
first, create a context file in app folder(TitleContext.tsx)


import React, { createContext, useContext, useMemo } from 'react';

const TitleContext = createContext<string[]>([]);

export const useTitleSegments = () => useContext(TitleContext);

export const TitleProvider = ({ segment, children }: { segment: string, children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const parentSegments = useTitleSegments();
  const segments = useMemo(() => [...parentSegments, segment], [parentSegments, segment]);

  return (
    <TitleContext.Provider value={segments}>
      {children}
    </TitleContext.Provider>
  );
};



then Update your layout.tsx to wrap the children inside title provider


import { TitleProvider } from './TitleContext';

export const metadata = {
  title: { template: 'Studio - %s', default: 'Studio' },
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <TitleProvider segment="Studio">
      {children}
    </TitleProvider>
  );
}



next add titles together inside individual page layout pages, example project-review/history/page.tsx


import { useTitleSegments } from '../../TitleContext';

export const metadata = {
  title: { default: 'History' },
};

export default function HistoryPage() {
  const titleSegments = useTitleSegments();
  const title = titleSegments.join(' - '); // "Studio - Project Review - History"

  // Use this title for dynamic head or pass it as metadata if needed.
  return (
    <>
      <head>
        <title>{title}</title>
      </head>
      <main>
        <h1>{title}</h1>
        {/* Page content */}
      </main>
    </>
  );
}



